# Compute the sum of all the solutions of $(3x+1)(x-7)+(x-3)(3x+1)=0$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I need to compute the sum of all the solutions of: $$(3x+1)(x-7)+(x-3)(3x+1)=0.$$
I need to express the answer as a fraction.

Comment: Are you familiar with the rule that the sum of zeros of a quadratic (a similar result exists for higher degrees as well)
$$ax^2+bx+c$$ is equal to $-b/a$? BTW. I removed a sentence that will act as a lightning rod of negative attention :-)

Answer (score 4):

Notice that we can factor as our first step:
\begin{align*}
0
&= (3x+1)(x−7)+(x−3)(3x+1)\\
&= (3x + 1)(~ (x - 7) + (x - 3) ~)\\
&= (3x + 1)(2x - 10)\\
&= 2(x - 5)(3x + 1)
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it in my opinion is to expand sides and combine like terms, then you could either factor or use the quadratic formula.

$$(3x+1)(x-7)+(x-3)(3x+1)=0$$$$(3x^2-21x+x-7)+(3x^2+x-9x-3)=0$$$$(6x^2-28x-10)=0$$

$$2(3x^2-14x-5)=0$$

$$3x^2-14x-5=0$$

$$(3x+1)(x-5)=0$$

$x=5$,
$x=-\frac{1}{3}$

Comment: i tried this answer and it does not work

Comment: What do you mean it doesnt work? Have you tried to plug in the values?

Comment: never mind thank you!

Comment: also do you think you could help me with this problem, i have a lot of homework:Simplify \dfrac{1}{\sqrt2-1}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt2+1} as much as possible.

Comment: so would you be able to help help me with my newest problem?